# Joining Windows host to a Samba Active Directory failed

Tags: linux, samba, active-directory, ubuntu-14.04

I couldn't join a Windows (2k3) computer to a Samba4 Active Directory, because I got this message on the host:

> Error occured joining the domain. The specified network name is no longer available.

I got sereval warnings when I start Samba (in log.samba):

```
[2016/05/28 17:28:45.075722,  0] ../source4/smbd/server.c:490(binary_smbd_main)
  samba: using 'standard' process model
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
[2016/05/28 17:28:45.107472,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
samba: setproctitle not initialized, please either call setproctitle_init() or link against libbsd-ctor.
  STATUS=daemon 'samba' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2016/05/28 17:28:45.118242,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:328(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/winbindd: Failed to exec child - No such file or directory
[2016/05/28 17:28:45.123154,  0] ../source4/winbind/winbindd.c:47(winbindd_done)
  winbindd daemon died with exit status 255
[2016/05/28 17:28:45.123264,  0] ../source4/smbd/service_task.c:35(task_server_terminate)
  task_server_terminate: [winbindd child process exited]
[2016/05/28 17:28:45.124258,  0] ../source4/smbd/server.c:211(samba_terminate)
  samba_terminate: winbindd child process exited
[2016/05/28 17:28:45.824903,  0] ../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:323(dnsupdate_spnupdate_done)
  ../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:323: Failed SPN update - NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

My /etc/hosts (subsequently corrected with correct addresses):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
172.16.0.10     omega.open.local
172.16.0.10     OMEGA.open.local
172.16.0.10     open.local
172.16.0.10     OMEGA
172.16.0.10     omega
172.16.0.10     OPEN
172.16.0.10     OPEN.LOCAL
```

My /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 172.16.0.10
search open.local
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 172.16.0.10
search open.local
```

If I run nslookup omega.open.local, I get my server IP correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't caused by the errors shown in the log. I tried to solve the problem several times, and finally I found the solution (on [this website](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324439)):

> ... adding winbind package solves it (probably better to reboot after adding it, instead of trying to restart all samba services). It doesn't say you need any special winbind config.

Before I found the answer, I downgraded Samba to version 4.3.9, and added these lines to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, so I'm not sure whether these two steps are required.

```
idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes 
server signing = Auto
```

Before solving the problem I couldn't access resources shared by the server using `//SERVERNAME` path and I couldn't execute this command successfully:

```
smbclient -L localhost -U%
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hosts file entry incorrect for localhost**

Loopback on a local system always needs to be 127.0.0.1

Windows systems and some linux will test their local IP stack as a part of the join process and call themselves regarding netbios and RPC calls.

When the system tries to resolve itself it is failing.

You need to be able to ping localhost and ping loopback and get the address back 127.0.0.1

If you cannot, joining will fail.

Your first entry in hosts `27.0.0.1       localhost` needs to be `127.0.0.1       localhost`

Correct that entry and see what happens.  Hope this helpful.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I misspelled the address, and this setting is correct on the system. Any other ideas?

Comment: sorry no.  other than, do you have the DNS ip address of the samba server populated into the DNS settings of the windows desktop?

Comment: The host's settings seems to be OK, it can ping the server by its hostname so it can resolve the hostname. I will try to reinstall the entire server, and reconfigure everything.

Comment: It's resolving the hostname via broadcast more than likely.  Ensure you can ping loopback and ping localhost too.   :-)   good luck!